# trying to remove a character from a string works in the console but not at the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, text

I am trying to remove `-` character from text links by using following jquery snippet:

```
$('.footer-widget li a').each(function(){
    var str = $(this).text();  
    str = str.replace(/-/g, "");  
    console.log(str); 
});
```

In the console the character will be removed, but not at the page itself. 
See left footer widget of [My site](http://fhchp.de).

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you do it server side? In fact, why do you have to remove them? Just don't add them if you don't want them

Comment: It seems error is gone. Have any of answers helped you? Pleas mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the text on the page use `text()` to update each element

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.footer-widget li a').each(function(i,v){
              var str = $(this).text();  
              str = str.replace(/-/g, "");  
              console.log(str); 
              $(v).text(str);
          });
});
```

Comment: Posted at 11:46:13

Comment: depends on your clock :))

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method with callback which iterates over the elements and text can be updated based on old value.

```
$('.footer-widget li a').text(function(i,v){
    return v.replace(/-/g, "");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.footer-widget li a').each(function(){
          var str = $(this).text();  
          $(this).text(str.replace(/-/g, "");
          console.log(str); 
      });
```

Comment: Posted at 11:46:21

Answer (score 0):

you got it right but forgot it set the value back to it.

```
$(".footer-widget li a").text(str);
```

Comment: Posted at 11:46:26

Answer (score 0):

If you open browser console (or some web development tool) you can see error in your script

```
TypeError: $(...).replace is not a function
        $('.footer-widget li a').replace(/\-/g, '+');
```

It may have many possible reasons, but mostly it maybe because jQuery library isnt initialized yet. And therefore all scripts using jQuery should be surrounded with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ....
});
```

**More importantly** it seem you DONT have jQuery core library included in your page, only some UI plugins. If I open browser console, I cant use jQuery as well. You may have some improved browser console with jQuery included.

I found your jQuery library is commented out

```
<!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='http://fhchp.de/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script> -->
```